# ASP @Html.HiddenFor not posting data

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model

So I've got a simple model called `BaseModel` that has properties all models need. Like for example my `Provider` class.

```
public Provider Provider { get; set; }
```

And I have a `SearchModel` that derives from `BaseModel`. It just has an extra string and list.

Now in my html file I have this:

In the top I declared my model:

```
@model SearchModel
```

And in my page, I have this form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchText)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Provider)

    <button id="BtnSearch" type="submit">Search</button>
}
```

And finally this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
{
    Session["Provider"] = model.Provider;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchText)) model.Search();
    return View(model);
}
```

Only what seems to happen is, `Provider` is `null` when it reaches my POST action. The weird thing is, it worked in the past and I don't recall changing anything.

Comment: `"it worked in the past"` - Only if you have a very custom model binder, in which case you should be looking at that.  `Provider` is a complex object and by default what would be output to that hidden form element is just the name of the class (unless you override `.ToString()`).  Which certainly isn't going to deserialize back to an instance of the class.  In the HTML sent to the browser, what's the actual contents of the hidden form field?

Comment: It transforms into `<input id="Provider" name="Provider" type="hidden" value="Killer_App.Helpers.Providers.Provider">`

Comment: Indeed, the string `Killer_App.Helpers.Providers.Provider` doesn't really contain information for re-building an instance of the class.  How complex is `Provider`?  If I remember correctly, one simple approach could be to create the hidden fields for its properties.  For example: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Provider.SomeField)` and so on for the fields you want to persist across requests for `Provider`.  If it gets unwieldy, you could create a custom HTML helper template for the `Provider` type.

Comment: Oh no `Provider` is an object that holds multiple objects. I'll try some other way.

Comment: In that case you'll probably want to build a custom editor template for that type.  Then you'd simply use @Html.EditorFor() to invoke that template.

Comment: have you checked your ModelState ??

Comment: What does that do?